# Can't paste file name in Save dialog in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, filemanager

I just upgraded Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. With the old version, I could paste (`Ctrl+V`) the file name when saving a file from Chrome browser. The new version allows for typing or editing the file name, but doesn't react to `Ctrl+V`. Here is a sample screen capture:

[image]

I'm trying to change `paper.pdf` file name into something else. Is there a way around it, other than getting rid of Gnome?

Comment: I notice the same behavior. Additionally, whe I try to paste any text into the name field, an error message pops up, stating “The folder contents could not be displayed” and “Vorgang wird nicht unterstützt” (operation is not supported).

Comment: @Marvo I just found a solution: right-click on the text and select Paste.

Comment: Confirmed. Thank you for posting the solution. Interestingly, this problem seems to affect only the browsers Chrome, Chromium and Firefox. I could not reproduce it with any other program.

Comment: @Marvo I just solved an unrelated problem by disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome and the paste problem went away too.